# How do I run a shell command on startup on Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, boot, wsl-2

Im using WSL and want run the shell command "export DISPLAY=:0" on startup so I can use gui applications. How do I do this?

Comment: Maybe add that to your `.bashrc`?

Answer (score 0):

`echo "export DISPLAY=:0" >> ~/.bashrc`